# Run single testsuite with Gradle Java

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, test-suite

This is my Gradle script:

```
test{
    include 'com.foo.MainTestSuite'
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

And this is my com.foo.MainTestSuite

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        NetworkTestSuite.class,
        DataBaseTestSuite.class
})
public class MainTestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup(){
        System.out.println("BeforeClass MainTestSuite");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("AfterClass MainTestSuite");
    }
}
```

And then I execute Gradle via command line like that:

```
./gradlew clean test
```

But no tests are been run. If I remove the `include` then all of my tests run but more than once since they are linked from testsuite as well.

What is wrong with my Gradle script, why aren't the MainTestSuite is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your test section in `build.gradle` to the following:

```
test{
    filter{
        includeTestsMatching 'com.foo.MainTestSuite'
    }
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

That will result in exactly what you want

Please refer to the [Gradle Test Filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering) documentation for further details